# Using galera mariadb with jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I've created a mariadb cluster and I'm trying to get a Java application to be able to failover to another host when one of them dies.

I've created an application that creates a connection with `"jdbc:mysql:sequential://host1,host2,host3/database?socketTimeout=2000&autoReconnect=true"`. The application makes a query in a loop every second. If I kill the node where the application is currently executing the query (Statement.executeQuery()) I get a SQLException because of a timeout. I can catch the exception and re-execute the statement and I see that the request is being sent to another server, so failover in that case works ok. But I was expecting that executeQuery() would not throw an exception and silently retry another server automatically.

Am I wrong in assuming that I shouldn't have to handle an exception and explicitely retry the query? Is there something more I need to configure for that to happen?

Answer (score 2):

It is dangerous to auto reconnect for the following reason.  Let's say you have this code:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE ... FOR UPDATE;
(line 3)
UPDATE tbl ... WHERE ...;
COMMIT;
```

Now let's say the server crashes at (line 3).  The transaction will be rolled back.  In my fabricated example, that only involves releasing the lock on tbl.

Now let's say that some other connection succeeds in performing the same transaction on the *same* row while you are auto-reconnecting.

Now, with auto-reconnect, the first thread is oblivious that the first half of the transaction was rolled back and proceeds to do the UPDATE based on data that is now out of date.

You need to get an exception so that you can go back to the BEGIN so that you can be "transaction safe".

You need this anyway -- With Galera, and *no* crashes, a similar thing could happen.  Two threads performing that transaction on two different nodes at the *same* time... Each succeeds until it gets to the COMMIT, at which point the Galera magic happens and one of the COMMITs is told to fail.  The 'right' response is replay the entire transaction on the server that was chosen for failure.

Note that Galera, unlike non-Galera, requires checking for errors on `COMMIT`.

More [*Galera tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera) (aimed at devs and dbas migrating from non-Galera)

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that. Although this information is very useful to me, it doesn't fully answer my question. Do you know if it's possible to have the driver reconnect on failures during a query (as opposed to generating an exception and then reconnect). I have very basic queries, so I think I can risk it. But your answer will definitely be useful to me in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about the Java connector.

Answer (score 0):

Failover doesn't mean that application doesn't have to handle exceptions.

Driver will try to reconnect to another server when connection is lost.

If driver fail to reconnect to another server a SQLNonTransientConnectionException will be thrown, pools will automatically discard those connection.

If connection is recovered, there is some marginals cases where relaunching query is safe: when query is not in a transaction, and connection is currently in [read-only mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setReadOnly-boolean-) (using Spring @Transactional(readOnly = false)) for example. For thoses cases, MariaDb java connection will then relaunch query automatically. In those particular cases, no exception will be thrown, and failover is transparent.

Driver cannot re-execute current query during a transaction.
Even without without transaction, if query is an UPDATE command, driver cannot know if the last request has been received by the database server and executed.

Then driver will send an SQLException (with SQLState begining by "25" = INVALID_TRANSACTION_STATE), and it's up to the application to handle those cases.